# which hash function to choose for indexing uuid string on mysql? md5，crc64 or fnv

Tags: mysql, indexing, hash, uuid

I have a column store the uuid string. I add a new column to store its integer(64bits) hash value for indexing. which hash function to choose?

```
1. int(md5('a306d9cb-4d75-4673-ae43-700470692521').hexdigest()[-16:], 16)
2. crc64('a306d9cb-4d75-4673-ae43-700470692521')
3. fnv.hash('a306d9cb-4d75-4673-ae43-700470692521', bits=64)
```

it`s a mapping table for third party account.

table example:

```
openid: o00HW1KP16EvXs5whqPH2qyx667s
appid: wxb25520ae9512cabb
uid: 135435123
```

(openid, appid) --> uid

used to create a compound index on (openid, appid).
Can make it faster if add a integer column like hash(openid, appid)?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: What MySQL version? Rather than a hash, why not BINARY(36). As a small string without a character set, this is quite quick. Why are you after a hash?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to hash a UUID for indexing it. You can store a UUID in a CHAR(36), or else convert it to BINARY(16) to make it more compact. You can make an index on a column of either of these data types.

Also, creating an integer hash from the UUID will remove most of the bits of information from the UUID, making it more likely to find duplicate values. You won't be able to put a unique constraint on the hash, nor make it the primary key.

So there's no need to index it, and it can only spoil the benefit of using the UUID in the first place.